# Nested objects in Django REST Framework when a field is required for POST and not for DELETE

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `serializers` while dealing with `nested objects`. Similar to the example by [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) I have:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True) #Not required for POST (see following)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, required=True) #Not required for DELETE (see following)

class PostCommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

class DeleteCommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)
```

I'm in a situation where I want *only* `username` to be required (validated) when **PostCommentSerializer** is used, and *only* `email` to be required when **DeleteCommentSerializer** is used. What options do I have? in my current setting, both email and username are required for both POST and DELETE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the validate function to check on both **PostCommentSerializer** and
**DeleteCommentSerializer** like this:

```
     def validate(self, data):
        if not data.get('username'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error message here)
        return data
     
     def validate(self, data):
       if not data.get('email'):
          raise serializers.ValidationError(error message here)
       return data
```